# Arrange data in ascending order in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which one of the column stores name.
The names are stored as John,jimmy,Steve,smith,Shaun.

I would like to display it as

```
jimmy
John
Shaun
smith
Steve
```

The name are displayed in alphabetical order.

Which query should I use in SQL SERVER 2008.
I have tried using `collate nocase` which gave me an error.
My database `collation` is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Comment: If you want case insensitive sorting ("Shaun, smith, Steve"), you can try using Upper function

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY [name] ASC
```

Doesn't work for you ?

Comment: Do you have some error massage ? Do you have any output ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**ORDER BY CLAUSE**](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php), It will resolve your problem

```
 select name from tablename order by name COLLATE NOCASE.
```

OR

```
select name from tablename order by Lower(name)
```

Comment: Order by name gives me jimmy,smith,John,Shaun,Steve

Answer (score 0):

With `collate` you specify how the column values are treated in operations, if e.g. equality check is case sensitive or case insensitive. This has nothing to do with ordering your values using a `select` statement.

The ordering is simply forced by an `order by` like already said.